# Java: Exception, Inheritance Concepts Unclear

Tags: java, exception, inheritance

```
class X extends Exception {
}

class Y extends X {
}

class Z extends Y {
}

public class Test {

    static void aMethod() throws Z {
        throw new Z();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = 10;
    try { 
        aMethod(); 
    }
    catch(X e) { 
        System.out.println(“Error X”);
        }
    catch(Y e) { 
        System.out.println(“Error Y”);
        }
   }
}
```

What is the output?

(A) The exception will go uncaught by both catch
blocks

(B) It will print “Error X”

(C) It will print “Error Y”

Comment: Why not compile the code and run it?

Comment: -ve vote. this is not quiz site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(D) It does not compile ;-)

The second catch block is unreachable.

If you turn it around, and catch `Y` first you still should get a compiler warning, as Z is a checked exception and the compiler will detect that only the first catch clause can be reached. But the example will work, and "Error Y" will be printed.

Java always evaluates the catch clauses in the order they are defined, which is the reason you should define the most specific exceptions first, in this case `catch (Y y)` should come before `catch (X x)`.

EDIT: In the first version I assumed that the compiler error "Unreachable code" can be turned off with special compiler settings. Thanks to Marko Topolnik for the clarification.

Comment: "Depending on the compiler settings, of course" ? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Many validation-type compiler errors are mandated by the JLS. Dead code is one of them.

Comment: There is no such thing as "more lenient compiler settings" which will make that code compile.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: You are right, of course. I got sidetracked, Eclipse does allow some compiler Errors/Warnings to be adjusted, "unreachable code" does not belong to them though. I will edit the answer accordingly...

Comment: You may phrase it as a counterfactual: *if* Java didn't require the validation of that case, *then*...

Answer (score 0):

It will not compile because method aMethod throws "Z" exception and in main method you are catching "X" and "Y" where catch of "Y" is unreachable because "X" is super class for both "Y" and "Z".

to make it compile and run,  try to catch "Z" and "Y"